# Can I rearrange perks in Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

I'm playing KotOR and the final is almost there, but for the first half of the game, I spent points I got while leveling up for useless skills for me. Also, I made a mistake because I split points in too many different ways. As a result of that, I cant wear implants and I have weak force skills.

Is there any quest, or just a mechanic to allow my character to distribute benefits from levelling again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no in-game mechanic in KotOR or KotOR 2 that lets you change/refund your skills, feats, or powers.